# bcp command not working in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, bcp

MY QUERY IS

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'bcp "SELECT * FROM NORTHWIND..COUNTRY" QUERYOUT "E:\NET\DATEFILE.XLS "'
```

when i run this command it show error

bcp is not recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: Remote on to your SQL Server and find the full path to the BCP.EXE file on your SQL Server. Use the full path your command line.

Comment: Or just write the full path to bcp in Windows PATH